# Pass props to dynamically imported react component

Tags: reactjs

I do dynamic import of a component

```
let that = this
import('./pathToMyComponent').then(component => {

    // how to pass props to the component here?..
    that.setState({myModule : component.default})

   })
```

How do I pass props to the component? 
I will pass the component to a router:

```
<Route path='myPath' component={this.state.myModule}/>
```

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

I have managed to solve it:

```
  import('./pathToMyComponent').then(component => {

    that.setState({myModule : component.default})
  })
```

Then in a function:

```
GetComponent() {
 let match = {}
 let match.param = {nick : 'userNick'}
  let Component = this.state.module && this.state.module.default
         return this.state.myModule ?  (<Component match={match} />) :  ( 
                  <div>loading...</div>
               )
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something like React.lazy or react-loadable, here is example from React documentation:

```js
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

more info here:

react.lazy:

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

react-loadable:

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Comment: React.lazy does not work for me. It gives error in Unknown element. I have spend a day trying to figure out why, and did not fund any answer. So I came up with solution I described in my update.

Comment: what version of React do you have? You need at least React version 16.6.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i have similar case where i need to load a **component** on a Click and pass props or params to it

here's my workaround

***DynamicComponent.js***

```
import React from 'react';

const DynamicComponent = (props, params) => {
  console.log(params); 
  console.log(props); 
  return (
    <h4>May Dynamic {params}</h4>
  );
};

export default DynamicComponent ;
```

***ParentComponent.js***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const ParentComponent= (props) => {
  const [module, setModule] = useState(null)
  const handleClick = () => {
      let params = { userID: 123 }; 
      import('./DynamicComponent.js').then((c) => {
           setModule(c.default(props, params)); // send props or params here
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
        <h4>parens{params}</h4>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Load Dynamic Component</button>

       {/* Render dynamic component here */}
       { module ? (
           <div>{module}</div>
       ) : null }
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicComponent ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) is how you can dynamically import a component, while still being able to use it in your code.. Meaning, you do not have to use the `.then(component => { that.setState ... )}` logic.

If you want to pass props to a route, you can do something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/somepath" render={props => <Test {...props} addedProp={val} />} />
```

I use a component like this to inject props to routes: (this specific example adds the previous route path into the props, but you could technically inject any prop you want here)

```
export default withRouter(
    class AppBrowserRouterRoutes extends React.Component {
        state = {
            referrer: ""
        }

        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
            if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
                this.setState({
                    referrer: prevProps.location.pathname
                })
            }
        }

        // Inject old route data into existing props so we can see where we came from
        addStateToProps = (existingProps) => {
            return {
                ...existingProps, // existing props
                ...this.state // old route data
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={props => <AppHomePage {...this.addStateToProps(props)} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/companies" render={props => <AppCompanies {...this.addStateToProps(props)} />} />
                </Switch>
            );
        }
    }
)
```